# Big styled picture not showing in my notification

Tags: android

I am implementing a big picture view to my notification in android. I first download the imagefile using the async task class and then pushes the downloaded image to my notification method. The picture is able to download from my servers(Because it shows the downloaded picture in the `.setLargeIcon`) but it is unable to show as in the big style format.

Below is what i have done

```
   private class Notification extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

Context c;
String message;

public Notification(Context context) {
    super();
    this.c = context;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

    InputStream in;
    String urls="http//myimagefile";
    try {

URL url = new URL(urls);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
in = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
return myBitmap;




    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    try {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) c
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(c, News.class);
        intent.putExtra("alliswell", false);


        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(c)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setContentText("message")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setLargeIcon(result) // The downloaded bitmap is able to show here
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
            .bigPicture(result)) // However it is unable to show in this format
    .build();


        // hide the notification after its selected
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

I was even thinking that maybe my image size was not as expected to be displayed in my notification box.
 I however tried the `.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(aVeryLongString))`, that also didnt work. I think I might be doing something wrong. I wish someone help me out because I have implement all the functions correctly from this source (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html) but none seems to work.

Please what am I doing wrong in my above codes, I would be grateful to know, thanks soo much.

Comment: The big picture style I think has a 256dp tall limitation. Check if you bitmap is larger than this size and re-scale it before setting it as the .bigPIcture(result).

Comment: @JTY I am using a picture which has 256dp tall but yet it is not showing. this the picture link I am using https://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png

Comment: @JTY I was even thinking that maybe my image size was not as expected to be displayed in my notification box. I however tried the `.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(aVeryLongString))`, that also didnt work. I think I might be doing something wrong. I wish someone help me out because I have implement all the functions correctly from this source (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html) but none seems to work.

Comment: how is it displayed in Android? Does two finger slide on the notification not work? And what device/emulator are you using? I don't really see anything wrong.

Comment: @JTY Please I am using a samsung device to check.